# Is it possible to remove the "new article" button from all sections in a Joomla website?

Tags: user-interface, web, plugins, joomla, joomla4

A mate and I are doing an internship at university, and the project we are working on is a small Joomla 4.1 website. Our supervisors asked us to override the mechanics of content insertion so that an article submitted by an author needs to be approved by a moderator before being featured for every visitor - as a result, we created our own Content table and a Status table linked to it. Also note that given the small scope of the website, we are also assuming a 1-to-1 correspondence between sections and categories.

The problem is that the Joomla UI lets any authenticated user upload articles and set them visible to all visitors through a "new article" button in any section. Is there a way to remove these buttons or override them with something of our own?

Comment: [Joomla4 has "workflows"](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/28648/12352) built into it for exactly this purpose.  Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange to reach an audience that has an intimate understanding of the CMS.  Most devs on Stack Overflow don't have the foggiest idea what Joomla has to offer.  See also [this comment](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/28431/joomla-page-builder-with-publish-workflow/28465#comment36740_28431)

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you for the tips, and I didn't know about JSE! I have been looking into workflows, but still going to post the question there in case we decide to go this route for some reason!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used the Joomla UI, but in traditional websites, you can use CSS or JS to hide/disable buttons.

For example, the "Ask Question" button in Stackoverflow (class name "aside-cta") can be disabled or hidden as follows:

CSS:

```
/* Disable the button */
. aside-cta {opacity: 0.1;pointer-events: none;} 

/* OR hide the button */
. aside-cta {display:none }
```

Or Javascript can be used instead of CSS:

```
askBtn = document.querySelector('.aside-cta');

// For disabling the button : 
askBtn.style.opacity = 0.1
askBtn.style["pointer-events"]= 'none';

// For hiding the button : 
askBtn.style.display = 'none'
```